# JQuery: Why using .find()

Tags: jquery

why are some developers using JQuery's .find-function like this:

```
$(document).find('.progress').show();
```

If you know the name of the class, you can just use:

```
$('.progress').show();
```

Even if i have ul-lists and want to select all li-children i can do this just with

```
$('li')...
```

Appreciate some clarity...Thanks!

Comment: Maybe for clarity to other developer who don't know JQuery. The first is self-explanatory where as the second isn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The point of `.find()` is to find elements within a parent element.

There is no point in `$(document).find(...)`.

Answer (score 1):

There is a performance hit to using a class directly since it doesn't map to native JS like `getElementbyID` or `getElementbyTagName`

`find()` will often be much more efficient (for pages with a large number of elements).

Edit::

Found the article I remembered this from. #5 here http://dumitruglavan.com/jquery-performance-tips-cheat-sheet/

> 1. Use find() rather than context
>      Indeed, the .find() function seems to be faster. But this counts more when you have a lot of traversing a page with lots of DOM elements:

```
var divs = $('.testdiv', '#pageBody'); // 2353 on Firebug 3.6

var divs = $('#pageBody').find('.testdiv'); // 2324 on Firebug 3.6 - The best time

var divs = $('#pageBody .testdiv'); // 2469 on Firebug 3.6
```